# How to convert Xamarin editor text to xml file?

Tags: c#, xml, api, xamarin, serialization

```
private void SMSend_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var text = myeditor.Text;


    }
```

I am trying to create a sms sender project with Xamarin. And text will be send through api.So i need to convert the text to xml. I am holding the text in the "text" field. I need to convert this text into the xml sytle like converting to JSON. I found something like 
`var xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof());`
 but I don't know if it is right to use.And I dont know how to implement these methods.  Thank you for helping me!

Comment: There are lots of Net library methods to create an xml.  Your xml serialization method is one of these methods. Any of the Net method can be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create a method to convert your text to xml as string.

Something like this will work:

```
 var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
  var sw = new Utf8StringWriter();
  serializer.Serialize(sw, typeOfObjectToConvert);
  ret = sw.ToString();
```

T is here the type of Object that you want to serliaze to xml.

I create a method for you that you can try :

```
 /// <summary>
    ///     Converts an object to xml string
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">the type of the object</typeparam>
    /// <param name="typeOfObjectToConvert">the object that needs to be serialized</param>
    /// <returns>xml string</returns>
    public static string ConvertObjectToPlainXmlString<T>(
        T typeOfObjectToConvert)
    {

           var serializer =  new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            var sw = new Utf8StringWriter();
            serializer.Serialize(sw, typeOfObjectToConvert);
            return sw.ToString();

    }
```

As an example :

```
 public class MyConfig{
          public string TransferUrl {get; set;}
           public string TransferData {get; set;}
         //.. all properties
     }
```

Than just call method like this:

```
var xmlString = ConvertObjectToPlainXmlString(MyConfig);
```